# How to get a promise to resolve naturally with request-promise-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-promise

I'm using `request-promise-native` module on node.js. The API I'm calling returns the required data via a GET. That works just fine.

However, when I try to get the data from the function which because it is preceded with Async returns a promise, I just can't get the syntax right. Here's what I've tried:

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');

async function usdToEos () {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET'
    ,uri: 'https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets/eos'
    ,json: true
  }
  const response = await request(options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      return (1 / response.data.priceUsd)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('\nCaught exception: ' + error);
    })
}

var usdToEosMul = usdToEos()
console.log('\n' + 'USD multiplier to convert to EOS' + '\n')
console.log(usdToEosMul)
```

How do I get the returned value to be ... the data ... (1 / response.data.priceUsd). This is visible in the ... console.log(response) ... but not in the variable usdToEosMul.

Comment: function don't return nothing. an when use asyc/await you dont need promise

Comment: @Daviti How would you fix this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the function which because it is preceded with `async` returns a promise

Seems like you nearly answered your question already. You will have to wait for that promise at your call site:

```
usdToEos().then(usdToEosMul => {
  console.log('\n' + 'USD multiplier to convert to EOS' + '\n')
  console.log(usdToEosMul)
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('\nCaught exception: ' + error)
})

function usdToEos() {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET'
    ,uri: 'https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets/eos'
    ,json: true
  }
  return request(options).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    return (1 / response.data.priceUsd)
  })
}
```

or

```
;(async function() {
  try {
    const usdToEosMul = await usdToEos()
    console.log('\n' + 'USD multiplier to convert to EOS' + '\n')
    console.log(usdToEosMul)
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('\nCaught exception: ' + error)
  }
}())

async function usdToEos() {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET'
    ,uri: 'https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets/eos'
    ,json: true
  }
  const response = await request(options)
  console.log(response)
  return (1 / response.data.priceUsd)
}
```

Comment: Do I have to ? ... I'd rather the caller ... my client ... not have to worry about async stuff and simply get a number or an exception.

Comment: @Knowself Yes, you have to. It's impossible to synchronously deliver an asynchronous result.

Comment: @Bergi You can turn a asynchronous function back into a synchronous function, but it involves blocking the event loop until the promise is resolved or rejected. Which is a terrible idea.

Comment: @3limin4t0r No, you cannot. Blocking the event loop would mean that the promise never resolves.